# Stormcrawler, the status index and re-crawling

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

So we have stormcrawler running successfully, with the main index currently having a little over 2 million urls from our various websites indexed into it. That is working good, however SC doesn't seem to be re-indexing urls it indexed previously, and I am trying to sort out why.

I have tried searching for details on exactly how SC chooses it's next url from the status index.  It does not seem to choose the *oldest* nextFetchDate, because we have docs in the status table with a nextFetchDate of Feb 3rd, 2019.

Looking through the logs, I see entries like:

```
2019-03-20 09:21:17.221 c.d.s.e.p.AggregationSpout Thread-29-spout-executor[17 17] [INFO] [spout #5]  Populating buffer with nextFetchDate <= 2019-03-20T09:21:17-04:00
```

and that seems to imply that SC does not look at any url in the status table with a date in the past.  Is that correct? If SC gets overwhelmed with a slew of urls and cannot crawl all of them by their nextFetchDate, do some fall through the cracks?

Doing a query for documents in the status index with a nextFetchDate of older than today, I see 1.4 million of the 2 million urls have a nextFetchDate in the past.

It would be nice if the crawler could fetch the url with the *oldest* nextFetchDate and start crawling there.

How to I re-queue up those urls that were missed on their nextFetchDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the ES spouts will get the oldest records. What the logs are showing does not contradict that: it asks for the records with a nextFetchDate lower than 20th March for the shard #5.

The nextFetchDate should actually be thought of as 'don't crawl before date D', nothing falls through the cracks.

> Doing a query for documents in the status index with a nextFetchDate of older than today, I see 1.4 million of the 2 million urls have a nextFetchDate in the past.

yep, that's normal.

> It would be nice if the crawler could fetch the url with the oldest nextFetchDate and start crawling there.

that's what it does

> How to I re-queue up those urls that were missed on their nextFetchDate?

they are not missed. They should be picked by the spouts

Maybe check that the number of spouts matches the number of shards you have on the status index. Each spout instance is in charge of a shard, if you have less instances than shards, then these shards will never be queried.

Inspect the logs for those particular URLs which should be fetched first: do they get sent by the spouts at all? You might need to turn the logs to DEBUG for that.

Comment: OK, that is very good to hear. It's possible that SC simply has not gotten back around to those urls yet.  How do we deal with the fact that all of the urls we are crawling are under the *.example.com domain?  Do those get distributed out amongst the spouts, or does the single domain hurt us in this regard?

Comment: depends on the value of partition.url.mode, if set to byDomain, they'll all end up on the same shard. makes no difference in the order in which they are fetched though

Comment: Yes, looking at it again, I think that what happened was that it attempted to fetch a url, then got an error (the server was up and down that day for other reasons), and when it went back and crawled again it created a new doc in the status index. so there were two docs, and for some reason all the ones from 3/4/19 never got updated again, instead new docs were created. So I think it is working. Thank you!